# Can I get $log to log the source code location of my call, instead of theirs?

Tags: angularjs

Here's something typical resulting from using `$log`:

[image]

If I would just use `console.log`, I would see the source code location of *my* call in the console. When using `$log`, I see the location of *their* log call, which is useless to me.

Is there any way to get a more useful result?

Comment: Have a look http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2542-logging-client-side-errors-with-angularjs-and-stacktrace-js.htm

Comment: Hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just dropped using `$log` completely. It really doesn't provide any benefit that we could see.

Instead, we're now simply using `console`, but with a small twist:

```
/**
 * @see https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/js/plugins.js
 */

var method;

var methods = [
    "assert", "clear", "count", "debug", "dir", "dirxml", "error",
    "exception", "group", "groupCollapsed", "groupEnd", "info", "log",
    "markTimeline", "profile", "profileEnd", "table", "time", "timeEnd",
    "timeStamp", "trace", "warn"
];
var methodsLength  = methods.length;
var console = ( window.console || {} );

while( methodsLength-- ) {
    method = methods[ methodsLength ];

    // Only stub undefined methods.
    if( !console[ method ] ) {
        console[ method ] = Function.prototype;
    }
}

angular
    .module( "util" )
    .constant( "console", console );
```

We're not overriding `window.console` as the original html5-boilerplate code does. Instead, we're just creating a new service and inject that whenever we want to use `console`.

---

#### Original answer

I'm not quite sure if this is where I want to go with the issue, but @BenjaminGruenbaum suggested to just use [decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide) and change how `$log` works.

This is what it looks like. And Chrome apparently even recognizes the pattern and I can click right through to the source code location.

[image]

So here is my proof-of-concept code:

```
var app = angular.module( "myApp", []);

app.config( function( $provide ) {
  $provide.decorator( "$log", function( $delegate ) {
    var originalLog = $delegate.log;
    $delegate.log = function() {
      var stack = new Error().stack;
      var location = analyzeStack( stack, 1 );
      [].push.call( arguments, location );
      originalLog.apply( this, arguments );
    };
    return $delegate;
  } );
} );

app.controller( "ApplicationController", function( $log ) {
  $log.log( "Hello World" );
} );

/**
 * Take a stack trace and extract a location identifier from it.
 * The location identifier represents the location from where the logger was invoked.
 * @param {String} stack The traced stack
 * @param {Number} [stackIndex=2] The element of the stack you want analyzed.
 * @returns {String} A location identifier for the location from where the logger was invoked.
 */
function analyzeStack( stack, stackIndex ) {
    stackIndex = stackIndex || 2;

    /**
     * Group 1: Function name (optional)
     * Group 2: File name
     * Group 3: Line
     * Group 4: Column
     */
    var callSitePattern = new RegExp( /at (?:(.*) )?\(?(.*):(\d+):(\d+)\)?/g );
    var sites = stack.match( callSitePattern );

    // The method that invoked the logger is located at index 2 of the stack
    if( sites && stackIndex <= sites.length ) {
        var callSiteElementPattern = new RegExp( /at (?:(.*) )?\(?(.*):(\d+):(\d+)\)?/ );
        // Pick apart
        var callSiteElements = sites[ stackIndex ].match( callSiteElementPattern );
        var functionName, fileName, line, column;
        // Assume either 4 (no function name) or 5 elements.
        if( callSiteElements.length == 5 ) {
            functionName = callSiteElements[ 1 ];
            fileName = callSiteElements[ 2 ];
            line = callSiteElements[ 3 ];
            column = callSiteElements[ 4 ];
        } else {
            functionName = "(unnamed)";
            fileName = callSiteElements[ 1 ];
            line = callSiteElements[ 2 ];
            column = callSiteElements[ 3 ];
        }

        return functionName + "@" + fileName + ":" + line + ":" + column;
    }
    return null;
};
```

I've also put it into a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/N47Ja3kQGbBLcyVJuOYK?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

See this it nicely explains about logging Client-Side Errors With AngularJS And Stacktrace.js

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2542-logging-client-side-errors-with-angularjs-and-stacktrace-js.htm

This will be helpful for those who wants to log the exceptions.